# Lagrange multipliers in optimizing a problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix, $S$ the square diagonal matrix containing on the diagonal the eigenvalues of $A$ such that $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2...\geq \lambda_n.$ I need to solve the optimization problem $\max v^TS^2v, \|v\|=1.$According to my book I should find $v=(1,0,0...0).$ We may use the method of finding the extrema of a function under some constraint. Thus, finding the Lagrange multipliers satisfying $\nabla_v(v_1^2\lambda_1^2+...+v_n^2\lambda_n^2) + s \nabla_v (v_1^2 + v_2^2 -1) = 0$ leads to $$ v_1\lambda_1^2 = sv_1, \,\,v_2\lambda_2^2=sv_2,...v_n\lambda_n^2=sv_n$$ If we set $s=0$ in the first of the two equations, assuming $\lambda_1 \neq 0,$ since $A$ is a non zero matrix, we conclude that $v_1 = 0$ from the first, and $v_2 = 0$ from the second equation which is a contradiction with the constraint condition. Thus $s\neq 0.$ The two equations finally lead to $s = \lambda_1^2 = \lambda_2^2.$ Thus, I do not how to conclude on the coordinates of $v.$ In particular, I can not see how $v$ should be equal to $e_1.$ The multiplier $s$ can not be expressed in terms of the coordinates of $v.$  We only know $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq...\geq\lambda_n.$

Can somebody help out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S = {\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\dotsc, \lambda_n)$. Note that $v\mapsto v^TS^2v$ is certainly a continuous function in $v=(v_1,\dotsc,v_n)$, so it will have *some* maximum on the unit sphere. You've already set up the Lagrange multiplier condition. After some rewriting, you'll find your system of equations is equivalent to the single matrix equation

$$(S^2-sI)v = 0,$$
where $S^2 = {\rm diag}(\lambda_1^2,\dotsc, \lambda_n^2)$.

As I said before there is at least one $v$ on the unit sphere which makes this true, and since such a $v$ is necessarily nonzero it is by definition an eigenvector of $S^2$. The unit eigenvectors of a diagonal matrix are $e_1,\dotsc, e_n$. Testing these out in our function $f(v) = v^TS^2v$ we see that the candidate maxima are $f(e_1) = \lambda_1^2,\dotsc, f(e_n)=\lambda_n^2$. Since we know $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\dotsm\geq \lambda_n$, it's clear that $f(e_1) = \lambda_1^2$ is the maximum and thus $v=e_1$ is the maximizing input.